# I wanted different answers of this query

Tags: expression, adobe

Confused with this long output from this query: new Date();
Can somebody cut short the output so I get those 3 different statements:

```
1.Date fx.(20 Apr)
2.Date & FullYear fx.(20 Apr 2020)
3.Time fx.(10:10:00)
```

Thanks a lot will appreciate :)

Answer (score 0):

Just read:https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php

```
$date = new DateTime('now');
$date = $date->format('H:i:s');
$month = new DateTime('now');
$month = $month->format('d M');
$full_year = new DateTime('now');
$full_year = $full_year->format('d M Y');

echo '<pre>TDate fx.('; print_r($month); echo ')<br />';
echo 'Date & FullYear fx.('; print_r($full_year); echo ')<br />';
echo 'Time fx.('; print_r($date); echo ')</pre>';
```

Comment: I know to add something inside the brackets will set a limit of a long answer